# Send HTTP Request to .netcore API having IFormFile input param from Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, .net-core, multipartform-data

I have a REST API in .netcore which is used to upload Files.

The API in .netcore has this signature.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("abc/{folderId}/uploadFile")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFileAsync([FromRoute] string folderId, [FromForm] UploadFileInput uploadFileInput)
{
        // Do something with the file
}

public class UploadFileInput
{
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I have to write a Typescript code to invoke this API and I don't know how to send the `IFormFile` type of parameter value from Typescript.

What I basically want to have is something like this.

```
export class MyServiceClient {

  public async createFile(folderId: string, uploadFileInput: UploadFileInput): Promise<string> {
    let _path = `http://apiendpoint.com/abc/folderId/uploadFile`.replace('folderId', folderId);
    let res: CustomResponse<string> = await this.send<UploadFileInput>(_path, 'POST', uploadFileInput, null);
    return res.data;
  }  

  private async send<TOut>(url: string, httpMethod: string, input: any, headers: { [key: string]: any } ): Promise<CustomResponse<TOut>> {
      const requestUrl = new URL(url);
      let request: RequestInit = {
          method: httpMethod,
          headers: headers,
          body: input
      };
      const response = await fetch(requestUrl.href, request); // fetch from node18
      return response;
  }
}

export interface UploadFileInput {
  file: IFormFile; // Need the type here basically
  description: string;
}
```

Please guide me so that I can invoke the API from Typescript code.